# Trying to scaleSize a markerimage from a sprite

Tags: google-maps, sprite, freemarker

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(9.967937,-84.15062),
        draggable: true,
        //icon: marker0000,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("/static/img/map/markers/1/sprite3.png",    
        new google.maps.Size(40*scaleFactor, 24*scaleFactor), // desired size
        new google.maps.Point(41, offset*scaleFactor), // offset within the scaled sprite
        new google.maps.Point(20*scaleFactor, 12*scaleFactor), // anchor point is half of the desired size
        new google.maps.Size(123*scaleFactor, 52*scaleFactor)), // scaled size of the entire sprite
        map: map
    });
```

Comment: Was there a question? A statement of the problem?

Comment: A link to sprite3.png would be helpful also (or an example/jsfiddle that exhibits the problem).

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [issue report (#4359)](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4359) on sprite scaling.  No activity by anyone after the initial report on Aug 19th 2012.  You might "star" that issue if it is the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: is a problem I am new in programming also in sprite and markers